# Oracle Apex connection timeout error

Tags: oracle-apex, session-timeout, connection-timeout

On loading the file from Apex application, I'm getting the Network Error (tcp_error).

Error Desc: "A Communication error occurred. The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time".

Please help me in resolving this issue. If increasing the timeout period fixes the issue, please let me know where exactly to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience before. This might solve your problem. I re-install my Oracle APEX with firewall turn off.